# CloudFront statistics show 25% incomplete downloads using Unity3D WWW class

Tags: unity-game-engine, download, amazon-cloudfront

i am using Unity3D WWW class to download AssetBundles in my game built for mobile devices. to serve the AssetBundles i am using CloudFront on top of S3 in AWS. according to the statistics that CloudFront provides around 25% of the GET Requests for these asset bundles result in incomplete downloads.
this seems quite high.
what is your experience with CloudFront and the WWW class. is this a worrying statistic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What are your clients? And what are the object size? If they are mobile, and objects are large I would not be surprised with this number

However to actually check where is the error, and if anything could be done here, you need to run some sample of clients that will directly download from S3.

If they will have the same incomplete download ratio, you need to work on making sure that broken downloads could be properly resumed by clients.